# How seting Eddystone-URL frames?

Tags: android, google-beacon-platform

Proximity Beacon API can Register Beacons with Eddystone-URL frames. I can't see it in [Proximity Beacon API Guides](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/register)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it is possible to register beacons emitting only Eddystone-URL frames beacons with the Proximity Beacon API.  The reason for this is that the PB API needs to have a **unique identifier** for the beacon (*beaconid*). Without that, there's no sure way to identify a beacon, and thus no "primary key" or other way to register it in the database.

A common solution to this problem is to have a beacon emit both URL *and* UID frames. Then, you can register the beacon with the unique UID, but still have it emit URL frames instead.

Comment: Thank for for your anwser. But I don't how to configure my beacon URL. If I don't use google app for physic web.  I want have my app can do it. How I set URL for my beacon.

Comment: Hey! Basically, every single beacon manufacturer will have its own way to configure or "provision" their beacons. When you get beacons from Company X, you'll want to go to their website to get a link to the app to configure their beacons. With that, then you can set up which Eddystone frames (like UID or URL) it broadcasts, and what values are in there.